# Need to remove 'test' products in Ecommerce Overview of products

Tags: google-analytics

I have used the Google Analytics Hit Builder to remove my test purchases on my Ecommerce sites Analytics, which has removed the Revenue ok!

But they still display on the Homepage view of my Analytics under:
'What are your top selling products?'

My question; is there any way to remove this product/text from the 'Ecommerce Overview'??

Regards!
Chris H

[Please see Example Image here of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n6qa.png)

Comment: I assume you *removed* the revenue by sending a hit with negative revenue?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all of your data by deleting the view and starting over, but you cannot selectively remove data.

Even sending a negative revenue with an existing Transaction ID does not actually remove anything; internally this is still stored as two transactions, so this affects your E-Commerce-Conversionrate, possibly your channel performance (unless you sent correct channel information in your second transaction) and might even be displayed as separate transactions depending on the timeframe you selected.

Comment: thanks simple answer instead of the remove revenue by sending hit negative revenue i found in a site... that only removes the transactions.